# Apache going to wrong directory

Tags: apache-httpd

I have a RHEL server with multiple websites. For this particular site, there are three different domains/subdomains that can access it. Two work, one throws an error. Here's my conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/yln/web
        ServerName portal.yln.info
        ServerAlias www.yln.info
        ServerAlias yln.info
        Redirect "/" "https://portal.yln.info/"
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html/yln>
                Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
                RewriteEngine On
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/yln_error_log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/yln_access_log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/yln/web
        ServerName portal.yln.info
        ServerAlias www.yln.info
        ServerAlias yln.info

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/1d40117d24e9b169.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/yln.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html/yln>
                Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
                RewriteEngine On
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/yln_error_log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/yln_access_log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`portal.yln.info`, `www.yln.info`, and `http://yln.info` work but `https://yln.info` (note the 's') returns a 403 Forbidden error.

In the logs is this:
`[Fri Oct 21 06:48:05.284438 2022] [autoindex:error] [pid 16786:tid 140094660904704] [client 63.226.23.69:26860] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`

Why is Apache trying to serve an index file from a directory I didn't set as the document root? And why is it doing it for only `https://yln.info`?

**Update**: In the conf file I showed, it's catching both portal.yln.info and portal.yln.info and sending them to the right place (same domain, SSL context). As I said the browser returns a 403 Forbidden error and I listed what the logs show. All variations of http and https work except for yln.info.

The SSL cert is a wildcard for *.yln.info. I should also note that the old site on this server is using yln.info just fine. (I rename that conf file to old when I'm installing the new conf file.)

Comment: In what way don't they work? Error page? Certificate warning? Unexpected content? Does your web browser consider portal.yln.info to be http or https?

Comment: Does your SSL certificate contain a SAN for each of the domain names or a wildcard for `yln.com` that includes `yln.com`?

Comment: @roaima, in the conf file I showed, it's catching both http://portal.yln.info and https://portal.yln.info and sending them to the right place (same domain, SSL context). As I said the browser returns a 403 Forbidden error and I listed what the logs show. All variations of http and https work except for https://yln.info.

Comment: @doneal24, the SSL cert is a wildcard for *.yln.info. I should also note that the old site on this server is using https://yln.info just fine. (I rename that conf file to old when I'm installing the new conf file.)

Comment: Chanel, please update your question to include the extra information. It's unfortunately too easy to miss detail in the comments - and besides they can get deleted. Make it easy for people to help you.